Discussion on the relationship between the FFT magnitude spectrum and the corresponding actual amplitude
This might be a bit long, but it's a question that has troubled me for a long time, and I hope to get everyone's help. When studying signals and systems, we usually only pay attention to the relative magnitudes of the frequency spectrum. However, we rarely discuss the relationship between the magnitude spectrum and the actual amplitudes of different frequency components in the signal. Recently, I learned that dividing the FFT magnitude by the sample count and multiplying by 2 yields the amplitude of the corresponding sinusoidal signal. I have conducted some derivations and reflections on this.

As shown in the figure, let's assume a periodic signal $f(t)$ with its Fourier series denoted as $F_n$.Taking one period of the signal and performing its Fourier transform, we obtain the frequency spectrum$F_0(j\omega)$.It is known that $F_n$and$F_0(j\omega)$:
$F_n$=$\frac{1}{T}$$F_0(j\omega)$$|_{\omega=n\Omega}$
According to the sampling theorem, the magnitude of the spectrum $F(e^{j\omega})$ of the sampled sequence  $f_n(k)$ is $f_s$ times the $F_0(j\omega)$, where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency. (Here, we don't consider complex situations like frequency leakage. we assume coherent sampling.) Based on the FFT, discretizing the frequency spectrum, and combining the above derivation, we know that$F_n$ and $F_0(j\omega)$ satisfy the relationship:
$F_n$=$\frac{f_s}{T}$$F(e^{j\omega})$$|_{\omega=n\Omega} $
$N$=$\frac{T}{f_s}$
Eventually, we can obtain:
$F_n$=$\frac{1}{N}$$F(e^{j\omega})$$|_{\omega=n\Omega}$
Therefore, the amplitude of the original signal's sinusoidal components is:
$2\lvert F_n \rvert$=$\lvert \frac{2}{N} F(e^{j\omega})|_{\omega=n\Omega} \rvert$
This method indeed leads to the derivation of the relationship between FFT magnitude and the actual signal components. However, it raises two issues:
①FFT can be viewed as performing the Discrete Fourier Series (DFS) on the periodically extended sampled sequence. In theory, the frequency spectrum of the impulse sequence signal obtained by sampling $f(t)$ should be the same as that calculated by FFT. Sampling $f(t)$can be seen as :$f(t)$ $\delta_{T_s}(t)$.However, both $f(t)$ and $\delta_{T_s}(t)$ have frequency spectra consisting of a series of impulse functions.Frequency domain convolution may result in the square of impulse functions. How should we compute this? Furthermore, according to the definition of DFS, impulse functions do not appear in the frequency domain.
②During the third step of performing frequency domain sampling, as depicted in the figure, according to the frequency domain sampling theorem, the amplitude of the time-domain signal will also change. At this point, the time-domain signal corresponding to the FFT frequency domain is no longer equal to the sampled impulse signal of $f(t)$. Do we still obtain the spectrum of the original signal?
